# html link tag color not changing after clicked

Tags: html, css, web

Link color not changing after i clicked. 
I used side navigation bar css style with links.
Here is my css styling:

i tried with active but still not working.

```
.sidenav 
{
height: 100%;
width: 200px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: #06799f;
overflow-x: hidden;
padding-top: 20px;
}

.sidenav a 
{
padding: 15px 20px 4px 18px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 25px;
color: #f1f1f1;
display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover 
{
color: #000000;
}

.sidenav a: active
{
color: black;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
.sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
.sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

expected:
is the change of link color when cliked

Comment: You probably want [`:visited`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:visited) pseudo-class

Comment: yes, but since it is a side nav bar , user must know which page they are in :(

Comment: Your problem can't be solved with plain CSS as far as I can see. You need to dynamically add an `.active` class with your required styling to the link. You could do that manually for each page individually (if it's a static page) or look into router options similar to what [Angular](https://angular.io/guide/router#active-router-links) and other frameworks provide. Here's one [independent](https://github.com/krasimir/navigo) library for the same. There's also [Scrollspy](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/scrollspy/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the visited color, in anchor tag, by using css, 
example given below,

```
a:visited {
color: #999999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `:visited` pseudo class to style visited links. ([Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp))

```
.sidenav a:visited {
    color: #BA55D3;
}
```

Using `:active` as you proposed only changes the color while pressing the link.